# $httpBackend.flush() causing Route Change

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have recently updated my Angular application from 1.5.8 to 1.6.1. 
In tests, $httpBackend.flush() started changing routes and broadcasts the '$routeChangeStart' message which started calling the functions that are listening to the event.

Am I missing something in the migration ?

```
//Function listening to the $routeChangeStart
$rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function (event, next) {
    console.log('This is called');
});

//Test
describe('Testing', function() {
  it.only('Testing', function() {
    //Code
    $httpBackend.when('GET', endpoints.endpoint1).respond([]);
    $httpBackend.flush();

  });
});
```

Comment: please share the code

Comment: @Codesingh shared

Answer (score 0):

Please add this: `$httpBackend.whenGET('url').respond(200, { data: "ok"});` in your test

Comment: What difference does it make ? 
$httpBackend.flush() is invoking the route change.